# SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL on one particular wifi on windows

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, curl

When I try to connect my windows 10 pc to my wifi and make a curl request I get the following error -

```
 curl -iv 'https://www.google.com/' \
*   Trying 142.250.182.196:443...="99", "Google Chrome";v="91", "Chromium";v="91"' \
* TCP_NODELAY setobile: ?0' \
* Connected to www.google.com (142.250.182.196) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2ozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.77 Safari/537.36' \
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443
* Closing connection 0
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to www.google.com:443
```

- I have checked the wifi and it has internet access because I am able to use it on other devices.
- Connecting my windows pc to a 4g mobile hotspot also works without issues.
- I have restarted multiple times, reset network settings, flush dns cache etc.

**Update after 4 Hours**

- Somehow the `curl` command is no working. But no page opens up in chrome.